# Files on USB drive containing Ubuntu

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu installed on a USB drive, along with other files. Is there any way I can access the other files from within Ubuntu? I can mount other devices like my hard disk and my DVD, but I can't see any way to get at the other files on the USB drive.

Comment: This depends on how you set up your USB drive for it to contain both Ubuntu and "other files"?

Answer (score 0):

Look in filesystem/cdrom. To see the files on the root of the USB drive, when booting the USB drive.